# Improved edit appears greyed out

Tags: bug, review-queues, edits, review-audits

I'm looking through the Suggested Edits review queue and came across some edits that could do with improving, so I click *Improve edit*. This works fine and brings me to the edit screen, where I make some changes. However, the *Save* button never activates and stays in a limbo state saying:

> Improving...

And is greyed out. I can't find anyway around this without rejecting the review and editing it myself, or hoping the edit is approved and I remember to come back to it later. Was a recent change made causing this issue?

**Edit**

I've also tried to enable it myself by removing the `disabled="disabled"` section of the HTML tag, but still not able to click that dang button

**Edit 2**

[image: Screenshot of issue]

**Edit 3**

There is a *Save Edits* button at the bottom that works, however I was sure that the top button was also activated upon typing some text, am I wrong and just having a senile moment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to click the "Save Edits" button:

> [image]

Then the review is done.

This "Save" button is at the ***bottom*** of the page.

Comment: Please look at my screenshot, it's a bit hard to do if the Save Edits button isn't available

Comment: Draken, that's not the "Save Edits" button. The "Save" button is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Has that changed? I swear I used to be able to do that at the top?

Comment: I honestly don't know.

Comment: Possibly I'm having a senior moment, could anyone else confirm?

Comment: It's always been at the bottom, to mirror the normal edit view.

Comment: Senior moment then, I think I need more coffee... Thanks @davidism and Cerbrus

Comment: @Draken Senior moment here also...I must be getting old...